# PL SQL How to handle no rows found

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
SQL - Cursor if no records not working

CREATE OR REPLACE procedure verify_data
IS
cursor c1 is 
select 
  e.name 
from 
  table3 e 
where 
  id IN (select id from table1)
  and id in (select id from table2);
BEGIN
if c1%notfound then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no records found');
end if;

FOR eData in c1
   LOOP

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(eData.name);
   END LOOP;

END;
/
```

My result will be output if there records. but if no record found, nothing is shown.. is there any exception handling or things i could do to make my output "No Records found" to be display if theres no record in the select statement.

Update:

I added after

END LOOP

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no records found');
```

and before END;

SQL> execute verify_data();

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Not displaying also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before end; add following code
`WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no records found');`

Comment: @user1587149 what problem you are faceing?

Comment: the problem i am facing is , it can display result when theres record but the issue is when theres no record, i want dbms output to print no record found and its not working. if i use your code, it doesn't print anything, just say pl/sql execute successfully.

Comment: since you are using for loop to fetch the data from cursor you need not bother about data not found because oracle handles this internally. Better you should go for open cursor then fetch it and have no data found in eception handling this is the one way.

Comment: work out will be have one bool variable before for loop set it true and in for loop set it to false. Then out side for loop write condition if bool variable is true then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no records found')

Answer (score 0):

Please check below procedure

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE procedure verify_data
    IS
    cursor c1 is 
    select 
      e.name 
    from 
      table3 e 
    where 
      id IN (select id from table1)
      and id in (select id from table2);
    BEGIN
    loop
    FETCH c1 INTO eData;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(eData.name);
    end loop;
    exception 
    when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('*** Exc: no data');

    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure verify_data
IS
no_result exception;
cursor c1 is 
select 
e.name 
from 
table3 e 
where 
id IN (select id from table1)
and id in (select id from table2);
BEGIN
FOR eData in c1
LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(eData.name);
  if c1%notfound then
   raise no_result;
  end if;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_result THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no records found');
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle NO_DATA_FOUND in cursor/loop

Try the below example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE verify_data
IS
CURSOR c1 is 
SELECT 
  e.name 
FROM 
  table3 e 
WHERE 
  id IN (SELECT ID FROM table1)
  AND id in (SELECT ID FROM table2);

eData   table3.name%TYPE ; 

no_data EXCEPTION ;
BEGIN
OPEN c1 ;
LOOP
FETCH c1 INTO eData;

IF c1%NOTFOUND THEN
  RAISE no_data ;
ELSE
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(eData);
 EXIT ;
END IF;
END LOOP ;
CLOSE c1;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN no_data THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*** Exc: no data');

END;
```